# Python Pie chart with Explode property on Power BI not working

Tags: python, powerbi

I am Pie Chart on Power BI which has exploding capabilities. I am creating a running Pie chart in Python and running it in BI by importing it using Power BI Python Scripts.
So far the code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib as mb
mb.rcParams['font.size']= 11
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "cursive"
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
numbers = dataset['Rev'].tolist()
names = dataset[events_counts'].tolist()
explode = (0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2) 
pct = '%0.1f%%'
plt.pie(numbers, labels = names, autopct = pct, explode= explode) 
plt.show()
```

How can I make it work?